# Sharing typescript types accros different projects

Tags: javascript, typescript, repository, share

I am building an app which has 2 repos. One is the frontend, using react, and the other one is a functions repo which is a repo containing cloud functions(the backend is firebase). I want to create another repo which will be a kind of a types repo so the front and the functions repos will share the same types.

Now what i have done is created a libs directory in which i set up a basic tsconfig and src folder with a test interface.
tsconfig in lib directory:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "composite": true
  },
  "include": ["src"],
}
```

The interface i created:

```
export interface Test {
  test: string
}
```

tsconfig in the frontend directory:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "../libs/test"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now i am able to use this interace in the fronend by importing it like this:

```
import { Test } from "../../../../libs/test/src/test-interface";
```

But i have a few problems:

1. I am not able to auto import it. I mean i cant just write the name of the interface and vscode would suggest to import from the right source. I have to manually type the import
2. I have to manuly build the types directory, and iwould like for it to build automatically when i run npm start in the fronend.

Is there a way to achive that?

Answer (score 0):

You can build your shared repo as an actual package that can be installed (e.g. `npm install --save the-shared-types-package` ). To do so you have to load the result into something that can be a source for npm packages.  Github does have a service that can do that for example: https://docs.github.com/en/packages/learn-github-packages/introduction-to-github-packages - as do many other vendors.

Main trick is you need a kind of publishing workflow on the types repo.